# Reading single line file in python not skipping some spaces

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read files in Python that have all the same structure but quite an original one: it doesn't seem trivial to read it with the default `list` and parsing tools, though I'm sure it is possible.
So the structure is: `int` space `int` space `double` space a long long string that contains spaces

I need to store the two `int`s and the `float` (file header) apart, then I'd like to have the whole string as a monolithic bloc, because my data is encoded at the bit level in each one of the characters (I hope I'm explaining it clearly...).

Using naively the `.split()` method doesn't help me because of the spaces in the string, I've been thinking about "meshing" all the elements in `split()` after the first three, but I'd lose information if there were double spaces in the string.

In C++, I'd be using `<<` for the ints and double, then `.getbyte()` for the characters, are there equivalents in Python?

Comment: Step 1: read the whole line. Step 2: user regular expressions to parse. Look here for examples of implementing regexes https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions?csw=1

Comment: What about using the ``maxsplit`` argument for [``str.split()``](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the .split() function. Since you know the format of the lines you can pass in the number of lines to be made.

```
str.split(str="", num)
```

Parameters
str -- This is any delimeter, by default it is space.
num -- this is number of splits to be made.
So in your case you should be able to do

```
str.split(str='', 3)
```

Which should split up into:

- int
- int
- double
- string

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed it is the right option ;)

Comment: The number shouldn't correspond to number of lines. It should correspond to number of splits (i.e. ``3``). The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) say: *If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements).*

Comment: Glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 1):

So the format for each line looks like this (I'm assuming that the string isn't separately escaped by quotes):

```
"4 5 8.7 here is a really long string"
```

In general, for more sophisticated parsing, it's recommended that you use regular expressions.

```
import re
[...]

for line in file:
    #let's say line is "4 5 8.7 here is a really long string"
    pat = r'([0-9]+)\s([0-9]+)\s([0-9\.]+)\s([\w\s\_\-]+)'
    match = re.search(pat, line)
    matches_by_group = match.groups() #Do something with this
```

This way you'll have each separate piece in a tuple for each line. You can then cast the double, int, etc. as necessary.